# complement of a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

If we have a random graph $G_p \in g(n,p)$ how would we show that the complement $\bar{G}_p$ is eqaul to $G_q \in g(n,q)$ where $q=1-p$?

I'm finding it hard to start this sort of proof so any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Note that a random graph is _not_ equal to its complement.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse, $p$ is the probability that two nodes will be connected. So $1-p$ is the probability that the two nodes will not be connected. So in the complement, the probability that two nodes will be connected is $1-p$.